# How to write the data received as response from the Fetch API into my pdf using jsPDF?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api, jspdf

I am trying to write the title of a website into my pdf. This is my code:

```
const doc = new jsPDF();

fetch('https://api.codetabs.com/v1/proxy?quest=https://arunachaltimes.in/index.php/2022/04/27/mein-requests-vaishnaw-to-start-murkongselek-pasighat-broad-gauge-project/')
    .then(
        function (response) {
            response.text().then(function(data) {

                const parser = new DOMParser();
                const htmldoc = parser.parseFromString(data, "text/html");
                let title = htmldoc.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].innerText;
               
                console.log(title) //shows the correct value

                doc.text(10,10, title);
            })
        }
     )
    .catch(function(err) {
         console.log(err);
    })

doc.save('myfile.pdf'); //completely blank pdf
```

---

The pdf is completely empty!! Why? When I `console.log(title)`, then the value shows, but I think the pdf is downloaded before the text is written into the pdf. How do I fix it?

Comment: I don't get what you're trying to say. You can try this code out in any javascript live editor and you'll get what I'm trying to say

Comment: So, what do you propose? How do I get this issue fixed?

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
const doc = new jsPDF();

fetch('https://api.codetabs.com/v1/proxy?quest=https://arunachaltimes.in/index.php/2022/04/27/mein-requests-vaishnaw-to-start-murkongselek-pasighat-broad-gauge-project/')
    .then(
        function (response) {
            response.text().then(function(data) {

                const parser = new DOMParser();
                const htmldoc = parser.parseFromString(data, "text/html");
                let title = htmldoc.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].innerText;
               
                console.log(title) //shows the correct value

                doc.text( title,10,10);
                doc.save('myfile.pdf');//sava in callback
            })
        }
     )
    .catch(function(err) {
         console.log(err);
    })
```